# Network Analyst takes so long

Tags: arcgis-desktop, error, performance, network, analysis

Is there some kind of limitations of number of features when we work with Network Analyst in SDE ? My net has **170.000** features, is it a problem ? Because it take at least 6 hours to finish the "Build Network", and some times with errors. Is it normal?

Comment: My network is based on 155,000 features and it also takes several hours (maybe 2 or 3?) to build. 6 hours are long, but not that strange... If you do not need to calculate service areas, you can deactivate the "calculate service area index" option, which should speed up the build process a little bit.

Comment: It's rare that a RDBMS would *ever* out-perform a local file geodatabase.

Comment: #Mesa I can't see this option (calculate service area index). Could you give me a clue fo where can a find it ?

Comment: Strictly speaking the option is called "build service area index", see https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area-index-steps.htm